# AngularJS ng-repeat items horizontal to vertical

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `ng-repeat` placed on floated left `<li>` and the list apears in horizontal is there any way to repeat the same but vertical like below:

from:

Item1  Item2  Item3  Item4  Item5

Item6  Item7  Item8  Item9  Item10

to:

Item1  Item3  Item5  Item7  Item9

Item2  Item4  Item6  Item8  Item10

Please help if there is any way to do this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, you can use [**`column-count`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count):

e.g:

```
ul {
    column-count:5;
    -webkit-column-count:5;
    -moz-column-count:5;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7j92u/2/)

Comment: It works but if support all major browsers.. Thanks @SW4